# what is the meaning of the phrase hopping fences?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I have seen this phrase in a skate park recently.

> Don't ever stop hopping fences.

What is the meaning of the phrase?

> hopping fences

Comment: In politics it means changing sides. It is generally regarded as a bad thing for politicians to do. Maybe it means socialising with the "wrong" people. Maybe it describes a way of getting exercise (though probably not). Context is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The billboard slogan 'Don’t Ever Stop Hopping Fences' was created as advertising for the audio company BOSE, whose portable audio equipment is popular with skaters.

I understand it relates literally to climbing over fences, something that skaters might do in urban areas in order to skate in restricted areas that may offer some challenges. But a series of [videos](https://youtu.be/T04H9Fx_jqY) created by the company in connection with the advertising slogan had famous skaters say what the phrase meant to them, such as "no limits".

Comment: Ah, I got it, hopping over the fence, I was confused about the word `hope`, `hoping`